# Android Page indicator with swipe

Tags: android

I have a requirement where i have to place a set of Fragments in a Swipe View. Underneath the swipe view i also want a Page indictor ? Is there any open source libraries that support this ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Are you looking for something like [TabNavigation like PlayStore app](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/04/tabnvigation-like-google-play-store-app.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the best libraries.

**Library:**  [jwVPIndicatorLib](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

**Tutorial:** [check this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-jake-wharton-viewpager-indicator-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use Action bar sherlock view pager library?

> https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: I want this. I want that under the Pages there should be navigation like 1 2 3 4 5 6. Clicking on the number will take me to that page. Very similar to like Google Search results ? Can i do this with the ViewPagerIndicator ?

Comment: ofcourse you can.In that library itself everything has been defined. @BadLuckBrian

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

**Layout:**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/icnSecond"
    android:background="#000000" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icnSecond"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/dot" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icnThird"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icnSecond"
    android:src="@drawable/dot />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icnFirst"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icnSecond"
    android:src="@drawable/dot" />
```

**Activity:**

```
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                icnFirst.setAlpha(255);
                icnSecond.setAlpha(70);
                icnThird.setAlpha(70);
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                icnFirst.setAlpha(70);
                icnSecond.setAlpha(255);
                icnThird.setAlpha(70);
                startMoving();
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                icnFirst.setAlpha(70);
                icnSecond.setAlpha(70);
                icnThird.setAlpha(255);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is **[Android ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)**.